# Is it possible to make a method like Q.spawn return a value in Node JS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, generator, q

I know out of the box Q won't support this, but I'm wondering if it is theoretically possible to do something like this:

```
var user = Q.spawn(function* () {
    var createdUser = yield createUser();
    return user;
});

console.log(user); // user is available here
```

Comment: You should rather ask what difference does it make

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I would say yes, it is possible theoretically, it's just not intended to work like that. That's why Q doesn't support it.

I'm not sure why `Q.done` doesn't invalidate the promise chain altogether, preventing further calls to `p.then` to succeed (maybe it's impossible), but right now (Q is at version 1.2.0 at the time of this writing) it doesn't:

```
var p = Q("Test");
p.done();
p.then(function(message) {
    console.log(message); // "Test" is logged here just fine.
});
// No runtime errors.
```

So `Q.spawn` needed only return the result of `Q.async(generator)()` after calling `Q.done` on it to support that, like this:

```
Q.spawn = spawn;
function spawn(makeGenerator) {
    var p = Q.async(makeGenerator)();
    Q.done(p);
    return p;
}
```

That said, it seems clear to me that the API doesn't want to encourage using a done promise chain: Contrary to `Q.then` and `Q.catch`, for example, neither `Q.done` nor `Q.spawn` return any promise for chaining.

The library authors were either not sure if this was a good idea (and so didn't want to encourage it, but didn't also implement something that prohibits done promises from being used) or were outright convinced it's not.